# Trying to sleep milliseconds time.sleep(0.001) not working as expected, alternatives?

Tags: python, windows, time

I'm trying to run a function approximately 200 times a second (give or take +- 50). When using time.sleep(0.005), I find that it sleeps for much longer. I understand that time.sleep is not accurate, but my use case doesn't need much accuracy either.

I searched this problem up and it seems to be an issue with Windows 10 & 11 in particular: https://bugs.python.org/issue44681

They don't seem to be keen on fixing this issue, so I was wondering what alternatives are there for sleeping for around a millisecond?

I tested this code:

```
last_time = time.time()
counter = 0
while True:
    now = time.time()
    if now - last_time >= 1:
        print(counter)
        last_time = now
        counter = 0
    counter += 1
```

Which gave me around 64 to 65 on my computer and around 70 on my laptop.